# Sorting array in php (OpenCart addresses)

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort the array $result by 'address' below. I have tried usort() but it does not work.

Thanks for all help

```
            foreach ($results as $result) {
            $this->data['addresses'][] = array(
                    'address_id' => $result['address_id'],
                    'address'    => $result['firstname'] . ' ' . $result['lastname'] . ', ' . $result['address_1'] . ', ' . $result['city'] . ', ' . (($result['zone']) ? $result['zone']  . ', ' : FALSE) . (($result['postcode']) ? $r$
                    'href'       => HTTPS_SERVER . 'index.php?route=account/address/' . $type . '&address_id=' . $result['address_id']
            );
    }
//The following does not work
usort($result, 'address');
```

Comment: Are you trying to sort them alphabetically? Also, the 2nd param of `usort()` should either be a closure or the name of a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make usort work, you need to define a custom function:

```
usort($result, function($a, $b){
              // ^ anonymous function
    return strcmp($a['address'], $b['address']);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Ghost. I got it working by using your function, and sorting $this->data['addresses'] instead of $result.

Answer (score 0):

usort needs a function as second parameter to sort your data, 'address' doesn't seem to be a function
You try to sort $result but you fill $this->data['addresses'] with data
I would fill $this->data['addresses'] with data and use the thing you want to use as key and then use ksort to sort it, example:

```
 foreach ($results as $result) {
        $this->data['addresses'][$result['address_id']] = array(
            'address_id' => $result['address_id'],
            'address'    => $result['firstname'] . ' ' . $result['lastname'] . ', ' . $result['address_1'] . ', ' . $result['city'] . ', ' . (($result['zone']) ? $result['zone']  . ', ' : FALSE) . (($result['postcode']) ? $r$
            'href'       => HTTPS_SERVER . 'index.php?route=account/address/' . $type . '&address_id=' . $result['address_id']
        );
    }
ksort($this->data['addresses']);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining that needed to sort $this->data['addresses'], not $result.